# Deploy customized kube-scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

I deploy kube-scheduler using https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/ .

I followed the steps exactly at the beginning however it does not schedule the node using "my-scheduler" the node is pending instead.

The log of "my-scheduler" pod is

```
E0207 20:35:43.079477       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: poddisruptionbudgets.policy is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list poddisruptionbudgets.policy at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:43.080416       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list services at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:43.081490       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: persistentvolumes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list persistentvolumes at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:43.082515       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:593: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list pods at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:43.083566       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list nodes at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:43.084795       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list replicationcontrollers at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.077899       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim: persistentvolumeclaims is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list persistentvolumeclaims at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.078410       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.ReplicaSet: replicasets.extensions is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list replicasets.extensions at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.079496       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.StatefulSet: statefulsets.apps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list statefulsets.apps at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.080585       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1beta1.PodDisruptionBudget: poddisruptionbudgets.policy is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list poddisruptionbudgets.policy at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.081675       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list services at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.082726       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.PersistentVolume: persistentvolumes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list persistentvolumes at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.083811       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-scheduler/app/server.go:593: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list pods at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.084887       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.Node: nodes is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list nodes at the cluster scope
E0207 20:35:44.085921       1 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:87: Failed to list *v1.ReplicationController: replicationcontrollers is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list replicationcontrollers at the cluster scope
```

It seems it does not have permission to access resources. I tried configured RBAC as the link says but it does not help.

Please help me if you ever tried this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the new scheduler use "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" instead of "system:kube-system".
The quick solution is:

kubectl create clusterrolebinding --user system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default kube-system-cluster-admin --clusterrole cluster-admin